# How to slices point cloud from bottom to top in R?

Tags: r, loops, slice, point-clouds

For bunny data example, I want to divided into 0.01 slices along the z(colume) value and without using for loop.
The picture is example for slices.

[image: bunny slices]

thanks!

```r
library("onion")
data(bunny)
points3d(bunny)
max(bunny[,3])
#> 0.0587997
min(bunny[,3])
#> -0.0618736
```

I used to use subset(), but i don't know how to lterate or using related package for my data.

Comment: The `cut` function will be good here - see the linked FAQ and also the `?cut` help page, especially the examples at the bottom.

Comment: if the linked answer does **not** resolve your question, you can edit your question to add more detail and people will vote to reopen it. `ggplot2::cut_interval(bunny[,3], 10)` should create your variable; `split()` will split your data frame if you want a separate data frame for each slice.

Comment: oops, `ggplot2::cut_width(bunny[,3], width = 0.01)`